# Error in sending mail from webpage

Tags: asp.net, .net

When I enter an email address in the textbox and press the submit button I get the following error:

> Error:The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string. Parameter
>   name: address

This is the code I use to set the address:

```
Mail_Data.MailTo =Textbox1.Text;
```

This error occurs when the textbox is not empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the code you use to send the email. Check the **Mail_Data.From** and **Mail_Data.To** properties, make sure they aren't empty.

Comment: Please post your complete send mail code. Also when you debug, is the Mail_Data.MailTo being set properly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mailmessage function then you need to call the Add to add the string

```
Mail_Data.MailTo.Add(TextBox1.Text);
```